# Adding a class to body if another element has a class 'active'

Tags: javascript

I have a button called `.burger` which is given an additional class called `active` that toggles on click.

HTML

`<div class="burger"></div>`

JS

```
var element = document.querySelector('.burger');
element.onclick = function() {
  element.classList.toggle('visible');
}
```

This is working nicely but what I'd like to do is add an event listener which gives the `body` tag a class of `.disable-scroll` whenever `.burger` has the class `active`.

How would I achieve this with vanilla javascript? I'm learning, so I apologise if my terminology isn't quite right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no need for another `event` that listen for the changing inside this `button` you could just toggle the body class inside the same event

```
  var element = document.querySelector('.burger');
  var bodyEl = document.querySelector('body');

  element.onclick = function() {
     element.classList.toggle('visible');
     
     if (element.classList.contains("active"))
        bodyEl.classList.add('.disable-scroll');
     else bodyEl.classList.remove('.disable-scroll');
  }
```

or you could simplify it as **@3limin4t0r** mentioned like this one

```js
  var element = document.querySelector('.burger');
  var bodyEl = document.querySelector('body');

  element.onclick = function() {
     const isAdded = element.classList.toggle("visible");
     bodyEl.classList.toggle("disable-scroll", isAdded);
  }
```

```css
.visible {
   background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<button class="burger">Burger Button</button>
```

Comment: You could simplify this to `const isAdded = element.classList.toggle("visible")` then `bodyEl.classList.toggle("disable-scroll", isAdded)`

Comment: I've gone for the simplified version and this is working perfectly, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to listen to DOM updates and trigger a callback when a particular body has a particular class that is being added, but I wouldn't recommend you to go this way...

It would make your code cleaner to find where you add `.active` to `.burger`, and there, add `.disable-scroll` to `body`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
element.classList.contains('active') ? document.querySelector('body').classList.add('disable-scroll') : document.querySelector('body').classList.remove('disable-scroll')
```

This will check if element has `.active` class then add or remove `.disable-scroll`

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) like this:

```js
var element = document.querySelector('.burger');
element.onclick = function () {
  element.classList.toggle('visible');
}

const observer = new MutationObserver(({
      target,
      attributeName
    }) => document.body.classList.toggle('disable-scroll', attributeName === 'class' && target.classList.contains('visible')));

observer.observe(element, {
  attributes: true
});
```

```css
.visible {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="active burger">Burger</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion (using *arrow function* and *ternary operator*):

```js
var el = document.querySelector(".burger"),
  bodyEl = document.querySelector("body");

el.onclick = () => {
  el.classList.toggle("visible"),
    el.classList.contains("active") ? bodyEl.classList.add(".disable-scroll") : bodyEl.classList.remove(".disable-scroll")
};
```

```css
.visible {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<button class="burger">Burger Button</button>
```